# Simultaneously using a symbol and adjusting the label origin of a marker on Google Maps: is it possible?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In the Google Maps API documentation, there are two methods to make a custom marker: using the Icon object and using a Symbol.

I am using one of Google's symbols for tracking a vehicle, and it rotates based on the vehicle's heading.

However, I also have custom labels attached to these vehicle symbols, and I would like them to be underneath the symbol (currently they overlay the symbol because the label origin point's default is top right).

The label origin is a property of the Icon object, not the Symbol Object. Is there some way to have the rotational capabilities of my symbol, use this built-in Google symbol vector path as the image, and also adjust the label's origin? I can't find one.

Thanks.

Symbol code:

```
icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        strokeColor: truck.color,
        scale: map.zoom / 2,
        strokeWeight: map.zoom / 3,
        rotation: truck.heading
      }
```

Example icon code:

```
var image = {
  url: 'my_image_url.png',
  size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
};

//---- Later point ----//
icon: image
```

EDIT: I can display the label fine. I can not, however, seem to relocate the origin point of the label when using a symbol. Example:

[image: Example of label with symbol]

Comment: Why do you think a label can't be applied to a Symbol?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  ([proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/voeqsw6j/))

Comment: Please provide your code that is displaying the label (a [mcve] would be best) or check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/voeqsw6j/), it adjusts the origin of the label. .